# Select Items based on a list containing the IDs

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of Items, each containing a field of Type integer.

I want to filter my list to get only the items that match a given list of integers.

The code I have now works but I know it could be optimized.

```
Class Item
{
    int ID;

    //Other fields & methods that are irrelevant here
}

//Selection method
IEnumerable<Item> SelectItems(List<Item> allItems, List<int> toSelect)
{
     return allItems.Where(x => toSelect.Contains(x.ID));
}
```

The problem I have is that I iterate through `allItems` and in each iteration I iterate through `toSelect`.

I have the feeling it is possible to be much more effective but I don't know how I can achieve this with Linq.

This might also be an already asked question as I don't know how this is called in English. This feels kind of stupid because I don't know how to formulate this properly in a seach engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to approach this.

Currently you have `O(N×M)` performance (where `N` is the size of `allItems` and `M` is the size of `toSelect`).

If you're just trying to reduce it *easily*, then you could reduce it to `O(N)+O(M)` by creating a hash-set of `toSelect`:

```
var matches = new HashSet<int>(toSelect);
return allItems.Where(x => matches.Contains(x.ID));
```

However, this is still going to be dominated by `N` - the size of `allItems`.

---

A better *long term* approach may be to *pre-index* the data (and *keep it indexed*) by `Id`. So instead of `allItems` being a `List<T>` - it could be a `Dictionary<int, T>`. Note that *building* the dictionary can be expensive, so you don't want to do this every time you want to search : the key is to do this once at the start (and keep it maintained). *Then* this becomes `O(M)` (the size of `toSelect`, which is usually small), since dictionary lookups are `O(1)`.

```
IEnumerable<Item> SelectItems(Dictionary<int, Item> allItems, List<int> toSelect)
{
     foreach(var id in toSelect)
     {
         if (allItems.TryGetValue(id, out var found))
             yield return found;
     }
}
```

(there is no need to pre-hash `toSelect` since we aren't checking it for `Contains`)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Join` which is more efficient because it's using a set based approach:

```
var selectedItems = from item in allItems
                    join id in toSelect
                    on item.Id equals id
                    select item;
return selectedItems;
```

Another way which is more efficient is to use a `HashSet<int>` instead of a list:

```
IEnumerable<Item> SelectItems(List<Item> allItems, HashSet<int> toSelect)
{
     return allItems.Where(x => toSelect.Contains(x.ID));
}
```

Comment: When using LINQ-to-Objects, it is implemented using a lookup on the "inner" (second) operand. This means that it will be building a `Lookup<int, Item>` on `allItems`, which is going to be pretty damned expensive (and more expensive than a `Dictionary<int, Item>`, since it needs to cope with a multiplicity that we probably don't expect). My point: be careful using `join` in LINQ-to-Objects: it isn't as obvious a win as you might think. You can see this in the reference source in the core-clr source: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Join.cs#L71

Comment: @MarcGravell: so it's an optimization to use `from item in allItems join id in toSelect...`?

Comment: I expect that would perform better, yes; it'll do a scan over `allItems` either way, but at least it only builds a lookup for the smaller set, which we can reasonably presume to be `toSelect`

Comment: @MarcGravell: ok, edited my answer accordingly, thanks for reminding me.